# How to read accelerometer data in Service with Android

Tags: android, service, accelerometer

Usually, in Android, we read the accelerometer data in an "Activity", by overriding the OnSensorChanged function.

I am curious how we can do it in a "Service".

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 7):

Actually `OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` is method from interface [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html).

So if you want to do it in service; you make your new class that extends **`Service`** and implements **`SensorEventListener`**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! I also just figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same in a Service as well.

```
public class BGHndlr extends Handler implements SensorEventListener {

    public BGHndlr(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
     }

     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         oSensorManager.registerListener(this, oAcceleroMeter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
     }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
         // do something
    }

    @Override
     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {}
}
```