# Android - How to count time over a long period

Tags: android, time, timer, count, accelerometer

In my app I want measure the amount of time that the accelerometer is at rest.

For example, if I set a threshold of 0.4 m/s and the accelerometer speed is always below this than it means that the phone is at rest (threshold is to account for jitter in values).

I want to be able to count the amount of time that the phone is at rest and upon reaching a certain amount of time at rest, then react to that event.

I already have the accelerometer working fine, I just need to count this time and I'm unfamiliar with how to do this, can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance

**Solution:**

```
  start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (vectorTotal > 10.1 || vectorTotal < 9.5){
        timelimit = (System.currentTimeMillis()+ 10000);
    }
    else if (start >= timelimit){
        checkUser();
        timelimit = (System.currentTimeMillis()+ 10000);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your app at the foreground?

At start:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Save this value in database or in preferences if necessary.

At end:

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then:

```
long passedTime = end - start;
```

Comment: After having some niggly issues with the alarmmanager class, I tried it this way and it was much simpler without the issues, cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

You could set an alarm each time you're above the threshold and when the alarm finally fires you do whatever you want.

Do something like this when you start your activity:

```
am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
timeoutInMillis = 60000;
Intent timeoutIntent = <create the intent you want to run here>;
timeoutPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, timeoutIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and then everytime the accelerometer is above your threshhold:

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutInMillis, timeoutPendingIntent );
```

don't forget to clear the alarm when you exit your activity:

```
am.cancel(timeoutPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer getekha, very helpful, I just had a few issues with the alarm manager when I didn't need it anymore and was unregistering my listeners, 1 alarm always stay set even when using am.cancel on the same pendingIntent so used DKITandroid's method . Upvote for code examples!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably looking at a dual Service/Activity solution where the Service runs in the background counting whatever you want to count and providing this information to the Activity when it asks for it.

As far as counting time is concerned, that is simply manipulating the return from `System.currentTimeMillis()` as DKIT Android points out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- Service to listening accelerometer. [How to read accelerometer data in Service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301636/how-to-read-accelerometer-data-in-service-with-android)
- AlarmManager to call your handler after specified amount of time. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

In service you listen events from accelerometer, on each event you cancel previous alarm and set new. Upon reaching a certain amount of time - you'll get intent from alarm.